# How can I show the taskbar only on certain displays in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

Is there a way to only show the taskbar on the display I choose? 
I need this because I just bought the Asus ZenBook Flip 15, which has the ScreenPad 2.0. I tried connecting my monitor to the laptop and altering the taskbar settings hoping I could make the it appear only on the laptop's display and the monitor, but it seems that I can either make it appear only on the main display, either on all of them, including the ScreenPad. 
I would like it to only appear on the laptop's display and on the monitor, but not on the ScreenPad. 
The workaround I have at the moment is keeping the ScreenPad disabled whenever I connect my monitor

Answer (score 2):

you must set your main display in the settings.
*(Settings > System > Display)*
Then in the task bar settings:
*(Settings > Personalization > Taskbar)*
Under the point "*Multiple screen*s":
Switch off "*Show taskbar on all displays*".

Comment: I have tried that setting, but it is not what I am looking for... I am trying to show the taskbar on some displays and not show it on others, whereas this setting makes it not show on any of them.